# Missing AssemblyName metadata on RestoreAssemblyResources item '*\playservicesbasement-16.2.0.aar'

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-analytics

"Missing AssemblyName metadata on RestoreAssemblyResources item 'C:\Users\sp\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\playservicesbasement-16.2.0\playservicesbasement-16.2.0.aar'"
when i install "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" - 71.1620.2
and "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" -  71.1601.1
then it's showing me this error. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try to clean the solution and clear the nuget packeges cache.

Comment: Hey Sourav, did you find a solution for this issue? I'm facing the same.

Comment: Valeriy Kovalenko, Nope I didn't find it yet.